# Update Windows Explorer associations without reboot

Tags: registry, associations, explorer

I wrote a code, that change explorer's file associations.

```
public void Associate(String app, String ext)
{
        RegistryKey extKey = classesRoot.CreateSubKey("." + ext, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);

        String prevValue = (String) extKey.GetValue("");
        if (prevValue != null)
        {
            if (prevValue.Equals("BAMP_" + ext))
            {
                extKey.Close();
                return;
            }
            extKey.SetValue(BAMP_BACKUP, prevValue, RegistryValueKind.String);
        }

        extKey.SetValue("", "BAMP_" + ext, RegistryValueKind.String);
        extKey.Close();

        RegistryKey bampKey = classesRoot.CreateSubKey("BAMP_" + ext + "\\shell\\open\\command");

        bampKey.SetValue("", app + " \"\"%l\"\" ", RegistryValueKind.String);
        bampKey.Close();
    }
```

Actually, it backup old file association and setup new.

It works well, registry is changed. But, explorer doesn't read new settings, until restrart.

Read offical docs and didn't found how to force it to reload registry settings.

Is it possible to force explorer to reload registry settings without explorer.exe process restart?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with restarting `explorer`?

Comment: It's project requirement.